# Multiple dropdowns without repeating code in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I have created dropdown `onMouseOver` with help of `state`. So far its working good enough. Because i don't have much knowledge about ReactJS i'm not sure is it possible to make multiple dropdowns with this or different method without writing all code over and over again.

Here is my code:

```js
  ..........
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.handleMouseOver = this.handleMouseOver.bind(this);
      this.handleMouseLeave = this.handleMouseLeave.bind(this);
      this.state = {
        isHovering: false
      }
  }
  handleMouseOver = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ isHovering: true });
  };
  handleMouseLeave = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ isHovering: false })
  };

 ............

 <ul className="menu">
   <li onMouseOver={this.handleMouseOver} onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}>Categories
     {this.state.isHovering?(
       <ul className="dropdown">
         <li>Computerss & Office</li>
         <li>Electronics</li>
       </ul>
     ):null}
    </li>
  </ul>

 ............
```

So if I want to add one more dropdown I need to make new `state` and 2 more lines in `constructor()` and 2 functions to handle MouseOver/Leave.So repeating amount would be about this:

```js
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.handleMouseOver = this.handleMouseOver.bind(this);
      this.handleMouseLeave = this.handleMouseLeave.bind(this);
      this.state = {
        isHovering: false
      }
  }
  handleMouseOver = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ isHovering: true });
  };
  handleMouseLeave = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ isHovering: false })
  };
```

I will have maybe 10+ dropdowns and at the end will be load of codes. So is there any possibility to not repeat code ? Thank You!

Comment: as answered, you just need to track the element you're hovering. this is possible using `e.target.id`...another example to achieve what you want https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/152072/

Comment: @Elmer Dantas Thanks for your comment.  I like your example, it is very simple and realy easy to use but it is not possible to move mouse over drodown window.

Comment: what do you mean by "over dropdown window"?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Not sure what happened but first time when i loaded page i couldn't move mouse over "Computesrs &  Office"/"Electronics". Loaded it again now its works perfect. Thank You gonna use this for my project, thank you very much !

Comment: @Elmer Dantas Okay i double checked. When you try to go with mouse over dropdown, 'hoveredEl' state is changing back to default thats why you cant move mouse over dropdown, But very strange, first drpdown will stay visible even if state is back to default '-1' and other ones will dissapear straight away. Basicly try move mouse over 2nd menu and then on dropdown where is "Honda"/"Tesla". You will not be able to do that.

Comment: @ElmerDantas Would you post your comment in the answer as Edgars found your comment helped as mentioned [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52011166/multiple-dropdowns-without-repeating-code-in-reactjs/52011577?noredirect=1#comment91009563_52011577)?

Comment: I've changed the code to work as I supposed it should and also post an answer as suggested by @SungKim. Hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use your `event.target` to achieve what you want. With this, you'll know which dropdown you're hovering and apply any logic you need. You can check for example if the dropdown you're hovering is the category dropdown like this:

```
if(e.target.className === "class name of your element")
this.setState({hoveredEl: e.target.className})
```

then you use it this state in your code to show/hide the element you want.

you can check an example on this fiddle I've created: https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/153708/

I don't think you're going to need the `onMouseLeave` event, but if you need you can follow the logic I've applied to `onMouseOver`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you ! It helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

### 1. You need to save the state of each `<li>` item in an array/object to keep a track of hover states.

```js
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    ...
    this.state = {
      hoverStates: {} // or an array
    };
  }
```

### 2. And set the state of each item in the event handlers.

```js
handleMouseOver = e => {
    this.setState({
      hoverStates: {
        [e.target.id]: true
      }
    });
  };
  handleMouseLeave = e => {
    this.setState({
      hoverStates: {
        [e.target.id]: false
      }
    });
  };
```

### 3. You need to set the `id` (`name` doesn't work for `<li>`) in a list of menu items.

*Also make sure to add `key` so that React doesn't give you a warning.*

```js
  render() {
    const { hoverStates } = this.state;
    const menuItems = [0, 1, 2, 3].map(id => (
      <li
        key={id}
        id={id}
        onMouseOver={this.handleMouseOver}
        onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}
        className={hoverStates[id] ? "hovering" : ""}
      >
        Categories
        {hoverStates[id] ? (
          <ul className="dropdown menu">
            <li>#{id} Computerss & Office</li>
            <li>#{id} Electronics</li>
          </ul>
        ) : null}
      </li>
    ));

    return <ul className="menu">{menuItems}</ul>;
  }
```

### 4. The result would look like this.

[image: demo result]

---

You can see the working demo here.

[image: Edit p7xr8ro9jx]

---

#### Shameless Plug

I've written about how to keep a track of each item in my blog, [Keeping track of on/off states of React components](https://www.slightedgecoder.com/2018/07/28/keep-track-of-on-off-states-of-reactjs-components/), which explains more in detail.

Comment: Thank you for answer. It is working but it is not possible to move mouse over dropdown windows. And i dont see way how to change menu names separately. One name for all menus ?

Comment: If you need different menu names, you'd need to pass them as props to the component and use them within the map.

Comment: Okay i see. thank you ! I like @Elmer Dantas example more but because he did a comment instead of answering i think i will need to accept your answer.

Comment: @EdgarsŠusts I ping'ed Elmer in the question comment. Let's  that he post his comment as an answer so you can mark it so 